# why is () => () not a subtype of Nothing => ()

Tags: scala, covariance, higher-order-functions, unit-type, bottom-type

In scala, functions are covariant in their output type, and contravariant in their input type.

For example, if `Dog` is a subtype of `Animal`, then

`T => Dog` is a subtype of `T => Animal`, and
`Animal => T` is a subtype of `Dog => T`

In other words, a producer of `Dog` can go where a producer of `Animal` is expected, and
a consumer of `Animal` can go where a consumer of `Dog` is expected.

So why do I get this compile error:

```scala
def useF(f: Nothing => Unit): Unit = ()
def f(x: Unit): Unit = ()
useF(f) // ok
useF(() => ()) // error

/*
example.scala:4: error: type mismatch;
 found   : () => Unit
 required: Nothing => Unit
useF(() => ())
*/
```

I thought that `Nothing` is a subtype of `Unit`, so `() => ()` should be a subtype of `Nothing => ()`, since `() => ()` is of type `Unit => Unit`. What is the difference in type signature between `f` and `() => ()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your logic is correct. Just syntax is wrong.

`() => T` is not `Function1[Unit, T]`. It is actually a syntax for lambda with no argument which results in `Function0[T]`. The parenthesis here is not Unit. It's a syntax to denote zero arguments

The correct way to construct a `Unit => Unit` is:

```
(_: Unit) => Unit
```

You can add explicit type annotation to verify:

```
val f: Function1[Unit, Unit] = _ => ()
useF(f)
// No error
```